# redis python async client keeps asking for credentials

Tags: python, asynchronous, redis

I've installed the latest docker container: `redis latest 31f08b90668e 117MB`
I start the docker container: `docker run --name redis -d -p 6379:6379 redis`
This doesn't have a username/password set. I can set/get a key like so:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> set "test" "testing"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get "test"
"testing"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

I install redis:

```
$ pip list | grep redis
redis    4.5.4
```

I create a redis instance in my FastAPI project:

```
from redis.asyncio import Redis
redis: Redis = Redis()
rsp: bool = await redis.ping()
if not rsp:
    raise Exception('redis startup failed')
```

The ping works. I should be good to go, right?!
I can even set/get keys at this point.
But, Later on I try to set a key and it blows up.

```
File "/myproject/backend/service/sesson_service_impl.py", line 51, in create_from_id_token
    rsp: str = await self._redis.set(f'session/{session.id}', session, ex=self._session_idle_sec)
File "/myproject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 2302, in set
    return self.execute_command("SET", *pieces, **options)
File "/myproject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1255, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
File "/myproject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1442, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
File "/myproject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 710, in connect
    self.on_connect()
File "/myproject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 748, in on_connect
    auth_args = cred_provider.get_credentials()
File "/myproject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/credentials.py", line 10, in get_credentials
    raise NotImplementedError("get_credentials must be implemented")
NotImplementedError: get_credentials must be implemented
```

One thing I've noticed is that the async connection is no longer being used. I've tried setting my own asyn connection pool but it seems to be getting replaced with a sync connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

I've been staring at this all day but I finally figured it out. I'm using a dependency injection library and it was supplying the sync client in one location even though I was configuring it to supply the async client.